# How to realize hot update when use Electron + CRA?

Tags: electron, create-react-app

I use CRA + Electron. And I build my project by target `electron-renderer`.

It works well while loading files in build folder, but it throws error when I develop and load url `localhost:3000`.

I guess the reason is that I use node api and electron api in react components. Anybody has the solution ? Thanks.

```py
TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function

   5 | var pathFile = path.join(__dirname, 'path.txt');
   6 | 
   7 | function getElectronPath() {
>  8 |   if (fs.existsSync(pathFile)) {
   9 |     var executablePath = fs.readFileSync(pathFile, 'utf-8');
  10 | 
  11 |     if (process.env.ELECTRON_OVERRIDE_DIST_PATH) {
```

Comment: I have to admit that I'm sometimes a fool. when I load url `localhost:3000`, I wrote one more `)`. Haha!